# Magento Installation Error

Tags: magento, installation

I have downloaded the `magento 1.7.0.0` and then i extracted & copied it to `www` folder of my wamp but when I navigate to the directory say `127.0.0.1/magento/` following `Exception`

```
---------------------------
Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger
---------------------------
An unhandled win32 exception occurred in httpd.exe [568]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.

Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

i am unable to resolve it............

Comment: Are there something in the apache/php logs?

Comment: From reading the error, I would turn off just-in-time debugging. It looks like it's caused by Visual Studio tinkering in your local apache config.

Comment: How we can turn off just-in-time debugging???

Comment: that wont work i had tried that in past

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried extending the max_execution_time in php.ini? Set it to 1800. You might also want to change the memory limit to 1024MB.

Taken from [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/errors.php/viewthread/279012/#t385498) thread.